Why illustrator is running slow?
I'm working with relatively big file (100Mb+) in Illustrator, and some operations are very slow, in particular, copy/paste of almost everything on the canvas. On my PC it takes around 15-20 seconds when Illustrator doesn't responce.
I have checked Task Manager to see where is the issue, but haven't really found anything. PC Performance looks like PC was idling. Total CPU usage was around 10%, and none of the threads was run even on 50%. More then 10Gb of RAM was available. GPU 3-5%. SSD and WiFi 0%.
CPU usage by Illustrator process itself was around 2-4%, SDD 0%. I also checked "Analyze wait chain" and found that Illustrator process is waiting for 3 different "Adobe CEP HTML Engine" processes. So I have also checked them but they all seams to me idle.
I also checked temperatures of CPU, GPU etc. in hardware monitore and all looks normal 35-45 Celsius.
My PC configuration:

CPU, i5-14600KF,
32Gb DDR5-6000,
NVidea 4060 Ti with 16Gb RAM,
Crusial SSD 1Tb,
Windows 11 with all latest updates.

How to figure out why some application is running slow when Performance view doesn't show significant load on any of the components? Or in other words where is the bottle neck?

Do you by chance have a previous version of the file? If you create a copy of the file does the performance improve? Do you have hardware acceleration enabled and have you tried to update your GPU drivers?

Thanks for suggestions. Unfortunately I don't have old copy of the file. Hardware acceleration is enabled and all drivers  as well as Windows it self is updated to latest version.
